# Remove duplicate value on nested list python

Tags: python, duplicates, nested-lists

I have a problem here when I want to remove duplicate in a list that has a nested list, how can I remove the duplicate value from list? What I got here from my script, it can remove a duplicate, but the nested list has a different result from what I expect.

This is my script:

```
# initializing list 
result = []
hasil = []
sam_list = [[11, 17, 11, 13, 13, 15, 16, 11], [4, 7, 11, 34, 4, 7, 11, 6], [1, 6, 11, 13, 13, 4, 1, 6]]

for item in sam_list:
    print("START")
    for x in item:
        print(x, result)
        if x not in result:
            print("NOT IN")
            result.append(x)
    hasil.append(result)
```

Result:

```
[[11, 17, 13, 15, 16, 4, 7, 34, 6, 1], [11, 17, 13, 15, 16, 4, 7, 34, 6, 1], [11, 17, 13, 15, 16, 4, 7, 34, 6, 1]]
```

Expected Result:

```
[[11, 17, 13, 15, 16], [4, 7, 11, 34, 6], [1, 6, 11, 13, 4]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize `result = []` inside the loop:

```
sam_list = [[11, 17, 11, 13, 13, 15, 16, 11], [4, 7, 11, 34, 4, 7, 11, 6], [1, 6, 11, 13, 13, 4, 1, 6]]
hasil = []

for item in sam_list:
    result = []
    print("START")
    for x in item:
        print(x, result)
        if x not in result:
            print("NOT IN")
            result.append(x)
    hasil.append(result)
```

If you don't mind order:

```
original = [[11, 17, 11, 13, 13, 15, 16, 11], [4, 7, 11, 34, 4, 7, 11, 6], [1, 6, 11, 13, 13, 4, 1, 6]]

[list(set(each)) for each in original]
```

Comment: Also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists for ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Almost there, you just have to reset the result list at every step

```
for item in sam_list:
   print("START")
   for x in item:
      print(x, result)
      if x not in result:
         print("NOT IN")
         result.append(x)
   hasil.append(result)
   result = []
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **set**. It automatically removes any duplicates, then convert it to a list again if you want.

```
sam_list = [[11, 17, 11, 13, 13, 15, 16, 11], [4, 7, 11, 34, 4, 7, 11, 6], [1, 6, 11, 13, 13, 4, 1, 6]]
set1=set(sam_list[0])
set2=set(sam_list[1])
set3=set(sam_list[2])

result = [list(set1),list(set2),list(set3)]
print(result)
```

the output is:
[[11, 13, 15, 16, 17], [34, 4, 6, 7, 11], [1, 4, 6, 11, 13]]